# Make polygonal hole in QImage alpha channel

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make polygonal hole in QImage alpha channel.
My current implementation use deprecated 'alphaChannel' method and works slow (because it use containPoint for every image pixel instead of draw polygon).

```
QImage makeImageWithHole(const QImage & image, const std::vector<QPoint> & hole_points)
{
  QImage newImage = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);

  QImage alpha = newImage.alphaChannel();
  QPolygon hole(QVector<QPoint>::fromStdVector(hole_points));
  for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); y++)
    {
      if (hole.containsPoint(QPoint(x, y), Qt::OddEvenFill))
      {
        alpha.setPixel(x, y, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  newImage.setAlphaChannel(alpha);

  return newImage;
}
```

I was also trying to implement it using painter and proper composition mode, but in result I have white artifacts on polygon borders.

```
QImage makeImageWithHole(const QImage & image, const std::vector<QPoint> & hole)
{
  QImage newImage = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);

  QPainter p(&newImage);
  p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOut);
  p.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255));
  p.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)));
  p.drawPolygon(hole.data(), hole.size());
  p.end();

  return newImage;
}
```

What is proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable antialiazing like this:

```
QPainter p(&newImage);
p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```